# Building a Docker (OCI) image with spring boot maven plugin has labels that are too long

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-boot-maven-plugin, buildpack, paketo

I am using Spring Boot Maven plugin to create a Docker image with the command `mvn spring-boot:build-image`. This uses Paketo buildpacks. It works fine, but the resulting Docker image has labels with a huge amount of data. It lists every file in my project. I have tooling (Falco) that reads the response of `docker inspect` and it breaks trying to parse the massive amount of JSON. In particular, I've noticed that the `io.buildpacks.lifecycle.metadata` label is huge. How can I get the buildpacks to stop using large labels?

Comment: Note that these labels and their contents are not a function of the Spring Boot plugin, but are controlled by the Paketo buildpacks that are invoked by the Spring Boot integration. There's a good discussion in the Paketo slack: https://paketobuildpacks.slack.com/archives/CULAS8ACD/p1604422121080400